# Why isn't my root domain's server DNS address found?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, azure, subdomain, root

I (thought I) followed directions to map a custom domain to a web app on Azure [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/). With Namecheap I made an A record and TXT record for the "@" root host, and also an A record and TXT record for the "www" subdomain. Only the "www" subdomain serves the page. Can I have an A record and TXT record for both? I also have a CNAME set for the "www" subdomain.

Azure's validation for both the domain and subdomain checks out, but the page is only served to the "www" subdomain.

Should I set up a redirect, like [rankmemestash.com](http://rankmemestash.com)->[www.rankmemestash.com](http://www.rankmemestash.com), instead? I actually tried this, but had the same error.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! In many cases mentioning the actual domain name is essential for the community to be able to help diagnose DNS issues. This may be one too. Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions. - Yes, you can have multiple records for the same resource, both for different record types (for instance both an `A` and `TXT` for the `www.example.com.` resource) or the same (two different `A` records for round robin DNS loadbalancing for instance)

Comment: Thanks @HBruijn. The root domain seems to be working now, just after I added it to the OP after seeing your comment. I don't understand why. Maybe it took some time for Namecheap or Azure to adjust something?

Answer (score 3):

For me your bare domain looks like:

```
;rankmemestash.com.     IN  ANY
rankmemestash.com.  1799    IN  A   162.255.119.248
rankmemestash.com.  1799    IN  A   168.62.180.173
rankmemestash.com.  3601    IN  DNSKEY  256 3 8 AwEAAeC7WrjzO6uujXivx5krP76N0eMEpojmae0/HHcoYf3GDSYADZ92 EjWAoY9V4ZMf+MnnKU0Dxk8rLwCQ0X6rsalr/UsGGrq38IZSyntvrpPp 48oFhd0NMKVXl6fnDpUHQeczkpGfgU1sXdL216BRw8VmS88rWD7A5yMv B3ibJU23
rankmemestash.com.  3601    IN  DNSKEY  257 3 8 AwEAAb3nuZ1z9+XHRu/WqxRlu1kpJsjdZAZs/c1+X+wlD+yv8CIzF51K xfW8jTYOHqX3zVJlHPq3LdNRurh1Vg09oIezKN3EvySVz1ER4Gg6OiU4 aOYiUXJdN0/mEp9YzG6lXa9GnYz17ZfxJ3T+gILkGgYI/sFrzCCL4Tt0 G7hBGC/DUHQWIVlo27uLEegImaWhtDv0YWiJTmvmAje6/rpm2Jhrw60k UwakT6nhpjQ0UBDDi4AxKDUTPYDlOIam5pjsemjMVXYaoWqk/Ec6dz40 BtR2/OJbKMYR56fHUp6sdxuAnIllYvjs6KC+SdL4VuXgWuD8CmEQfPLv bPb9BdimFZM=
rankmemestash.com.  1800    IN  MX  10 eforward1.registrar-servers.com.
rankmemestash.com.  1800    IN  MX  10 eforward2.registrar-servers.com.
rankmemestash.com.  1800    IN  MX  10 eforward3.registrar-servers.com.
rankmemestash.com.  1800    IN  MX  15 eforward4.registrar-servers.com.
rankmemestash.com.  1800    IN  MX  20 eforward5.registrar-servers.com.
rankmemestash.com.  1800    IN  NS  dns1.registrar-servers.com.
rankmemestash.com.  1800    IN  NS  dns2.registrar-servers.com.
rankmemestash.com.  3601    IN  NSEC    www.rankmemestash.com. A NS SOA MX TXT RRSIG NSEC DNSKEY
rankmemestash.com.  1799    IN  RRSIG   A 8 2 1799 20161103000000 20161013000000 38893 rankmemestash.com. yyTkImsCsmiv99/IVqC6fXKbhaPMv0M15h7sLQSnybwGdcnkeWugGFAC 2xx136R82G0O4X80Lc1ksWdwjZ/G+a/DghPNlk9aJBcxA1NHKQlUa4DR VhUcaHxaotCcFqPwT+xSGEfXfRcN9/IkCZVfMQvGU0PSKVz/48EDXnzC yTU=
rankmemestash.com.  3601    IN  RRSIG   DNSKEY 8 2 3601 20161103000000 20161013000000 41797 rankmemestash.com. seqDRP1doQrLigL54k9sIbbDiy9adN9pczDbNFqSCi87Y3516rQxKoJ4 BlVd6I/fTi7IqCPfznXpa/SgDulOUdR3zmU2OsDfY5eeDHBT6s19c6tp PYyAgh5Gp3ldELRzsiti+XSHxueCAtsyukrX3KYgK7c/FSN9CzCnd/vj UGsjLrahTxTSHLMpCFA2rBPylVMVU2tYfIP5PgQ9qSv/SOOhVvm/kyFD nrXxD8bUjqO7SRvGdjaF+O7uL71Axdd1AHDG+gPZzLF6GFoDYlcPKcRi ONsz+SiSsFDsRgt8ErK3lblXo/3dYxDzCY20fWMmR6CxyLIIcb5LKVrl OdFI1Q==
rankmemestash.com.  1800    IN  RRSIG   MX 8 2 1800 20161103000000 20161013000000 38893 rankmemestash.com. E7VxusZlRoiQzHMI9zhOSBOomVvc1BIhx0nMzYxu8izmqCUKBX1u2A7c b+OQNEWTI92uVYRx949MdYjCY2eSygWGS0prRTI+bBuLZulMwRZ/OPzj UzvBDBksXFOxUgl3e/DhBLgu5Ib30U5pKoJ1arNlIhD3yDPsa8j+YRj0 Zg0=
rankmemestash.com.  1800    IN  RRSIG   NS 8 2 1800 20161103000000 20161013000000 38893 rankmemestash.com. 0XjaMhaK7AK3x4zyuNrxZhlWsa9XqarR8QW4YB7dd1MPXgrQ5BzlDjda uJjjgKHCEzkp0QhTA+Yk8+sflEIDihIs/0t7y99h7c9gAa6w9ohFoDCX ao5oG4UsV3u/DSULSB3kW5IJ/01W78Ko3YQDAPmnBMPcFkHOppZlMLnv C8s=
rankmemestash.com.  3601    IN  RRSIG   NSEC 8 2 3601 20161103000000 20161013000000 38893 rankmemestash.com. rtld8mZ+ntLYGuAp+zPN87jgAsusa1woeeFlXoLOK0zPICclI4Sjt9tq N49ojnixgnqN9eakQZuNrnaiRN4Htm81ki/Bg8k4i1KeeDOXHPbC+9PF M6cBEjaAq+zv6YDynEyl6SsBlDJpcDv03kyzpFK5IZuVHQqhSYgTOOR+ 8rU=
rankmemestash.com.  3601    IN  RRSIG   SOA 8 2 3601 20161103000000 20161013000000 38893 rankmemestash.com. 19ppRPXqOQF3hlQyJ/oCwBbYSoZr0bnRLSMp7ERdtk4F7frnz8ShLv2E oIOea9/8gLzZK03kTqMLO5u/aIbKgFDajlrflEnSGikhOdGXCYiX41p7 9njjVfox5dtFfl0VgpQZsgDatXfYZP3Gqw3wyJlwwqUP7tt3manINomr Goo=
rankmemestash.com.  1800    IN  RRSIG   TXT 8 2 1800 20161103000000 20161013000000 38893 rankmemestash.com. jcAxnM89plB5hJdrpfrKYTqwP+h9a1Sy9wRRZfYACmJUZ/hd4nfIP5vZ sje6ytKRU+YK2pw3dFbnWBaTYEKnNZbLP9/HUZtH/qayFGSc+0WW/5FQ UWbS1AZ8hyEN6C6Rv01g5aJopRTXMvFMHmVBv1qDovw/NBFCdhmoW2XK sQg=
rankmemestash.com.  3601    IN  SOA dns1.registrar-servers.com. hostmaster.registrar-servers.com. 2016102031 43200 3600 604800 3601
rankmemestash.com.  1799    IN  TXT "rankmemestash.azurewebsites.net"
rankmemestash.com.  1800    IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:spf.efwd.registrar-servers.com ~all"
```

The two `A` records will result in [round-robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) where subsequent requests might resolve to those two different IP-addresses. That might explain why `http://rankmemestash.com` sometimes works and sometimes fails if only one of those is an active webserver. In comparison: the `www` record only points to: 168.62.180.173

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting and the wikipedia link is helpful. Would you recommend I set up a CNAME for the "www" subdomain, and use the A record for the root domain only? Or should I use a redirect? I surely have a lot more reading to do.

Comment: CNAME records are useful to reduce the administrative burden when you have many domains (that you don't control) but for a single domain and a handful of A records I don't see any benefit.

Comment: I had to reread your answer. I think I understand it better now. I don't know why there are two A records for the bare domain, I thought I only set up one. Thanks for the info!